# How to add label to plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

This is the graph:
[image]

I need to add label to graph lines. Blue line represents left and red line represents right. How do I do that? I used set_ylabel but that added label to left of graph as shown in it.

```
    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=96)
    self.ax =  self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    self.graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.win)
    self.canvas = self.graph.get_tk_widget()
    a = self.df["index"].unique()
    line, = self.ax.plot(a,self.df.loc[self.df.foot == "right","total_force"].values)
    self.ax.set_ylabel("right")
    line2, = self.ax.plot(a,self.df.loc[self.df.foot == "left","total_force"].values)
    self.clean_button()
    self.clean_flush()
    self.canvas.place(x= 150, y = 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use legend as describe here : https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify something more when you call the `plot()` method:
Instead of

```
line, = self.ax.plot(a,self.df.loc[self.df.foot == "right","total_force"].values)
```

Use

```
line, = self.ax.plot(a,self.df.loc[self.df.foot == "right","total_force"].values,
                     label = "right")

line2, = self.ax.plot(a,self.df.loc[self.df.foot == "left","total_force"].values
                      label = "left")
```

And then show the legend using:

```
self.ax.legend()
```